# IPad Screen Landscape to Portrait Conversion used Xib files with programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have an Ipad Application which is made with "xib" files this is in landscape mode i want this to support for both"Landscape and Portrait" I want in programmatically
I written this code it is working but some error
when I run the application it is not detecting wether it is in landscape or portrait if I change to another orientation this method is working and calling and working also is there any thing I have to give

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    if (size.width == 768) {
        [self portrait]; // collection of Components with Portrait Size
        self.forced = [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithHorizontalSizeClass:UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular];

    } else if (size.width == 1024){
        [self landscape]; // collection of Components with Portrait Size
        self.forced = [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithHorizontalSizeClass:UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact];
    }
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
-(void)portrait
{
    _mLogo.frame = CGRectMake(20, 40, 200, 80);
    _mCodeTF.frame = CGRectMake(240, 65, 200, 30);
    _mEnterBtn.frame = CGRectMake(470, 65, 50, 30);
    adonLogo.frame = CGRectMake(550, 40, 200, 80);
    _mView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 155, 730, 830);
    _mThumbnilScroll.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 730, 830);
}

-(void)landscape
{
    _mCodeTF.frame = CGRectMake(355, 70, 270, 30);
    _mLogo.frame = CGRectMake(45, 31, 255, 110);
    _mEnterBtn.frame = CGRectMake(670, 70, 70, 30);
    adonLogo.frame = CGRectMake(755, 31, 255, 110);
    _mView.frame = CGRectMake(12, 160, 995, 575);
    _mThumbnilScroll.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 995, 575);
}
```

Comment: any other solutions  for this

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`Use

```
 – willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
```

or

```
– didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:
```

instead of `viewWillTransitionToSize...` .

One will be handed the new orientation and the other will receive the old orientation. 
Working with the window's size.height or size.with is not a good idea for this puprpose or at least not by simply using an == operator.

Comment: this have to be used in every viewcontroller ?

Comment: when i run application for first time it is not adjusting as per the method i have written

Comment: Yes, these are UIViewController methods that you can overwrite.

Comment: You are right. For the first start you can determine the current devie orientation using `UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` or `UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;` You can use them in viewDidLoad or -better- in viewWillAppear.

Comment: Okay and after writing this i have wright conditions is interface is landscape keep this [self landscape] and if interface is portrait [self portrait] the code as i mentioned above in landscape and portrait

Comment: and know i have to wright the aove method didrotatefrominterfaceorientation: is that will be fine ?

Comment: Sorry, Mahesh, its weekend. Yes, you would do that in every view controller. I typcally create my own application wide subclass of uiviewcontroller and uitableviewcontroller who deals with that and let all other view controllers inherit from that.

Comment: in viewwillapear or viewdidappear you check for the current orientation. That is called when the view appears for the first time or when you return from subsequent view controllers or when the user returns from different apps. didrotate... and willrotate... are called on rotaiton events when the viewcontroller's view is currently displayed. There you transition to the new orientation.

Comment: With iOS8 or SDK 8 available there were new methods invented to achieve the same in Interface Builder only without programming at all. However, as of today, I still prefer the programming way.